# List all classes in a package directory

Tags: python, modules, dynamic-loading

I have a package directory `pkg` with several classes that I would like to build into a convenient `dict` property.

The structure of `pkg/` looks like:

**`pkg/base.py`**:

```
class _MyBase(object):
    pass
```

**`pkg/foo.py`**:

```
from .base import _MyBase

class Foo(_MyBase):
     pass
```

And in **`pkg/__init__.py`**, it is a bit clunky, but once `pkg` is imported, a `all_my_base_classes` dict is built with a key of the class name, and value of the class object. The classes are all subclasses of `pkg.base._MyBase`.

```
import os
import sys
import pkgutil

import base
# I don't want to import foo, bar, or whatever other file is in pkg/

all_my_base_classes = {}
pkg_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
for (module_loader, name, ispkg) in pkgutil.iter_modules([pkg_dir]):
    exec('import ' + name)
    pkg_name = __name__ + '.' + name
    obj = sys.modules[pkg_name]
    for dir_name in dir(obj):
        if dir_name.startswith('_'):
            continue
        dir_obj = getattr(obj, dir_name)
        if issubclass(dir_obj, base._MyBase):
            all_my_base_classes[dir_name] = dir_obj
```

Running it from an interactive Python shell, one directory below `pkg/`:

```
>>> import pkg
>>> pkg.all_my_base_classes
{'Foo': <class 'pkg.foo.Foo'>}
```

So it works as expected, but `pkg/__init__.py` is pretty terrible looking. How can it be better?

Comment: Why not import the modules normally in `__init__`?

Comment: Which version of python are  you using?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since the classes are all subclasses of `_MyBase`, they can be accessed via `_MyBase.__subclasses__()` after they have been imported:

```
for (module_loader, name, ispkg) in pkgutil.iter_modules([pkg_dir]):
    importlib.import_module('.' + name, __package__)

all_my_base_classes = {cls.__name__: cls for cls in base._MyBase.__subclasses__()}
```

For importing the modules, I followed [the advice of Nihathrael](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/70280/10916).

Comment: Cheers, very nice and concise answer!

Comment: `__subclasses__()`, fantastic! I also found [this answer very useful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3862957/327026).

Answer (score 4):

Using `exec()` is generally regarded as bad practice (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided). Since you are trying to import a module, you can do the same by using the `importlib` package.

Python 2: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html

Python 3: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib

Using it should clean up the rest of the code as well.

You might also be interested in this discussion for more possibilities regarding imports: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python

Edit 2:
Removed my code example, as [@janne-karila](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/10916/janne-karila)'s solution is even shorter and more concise.